# How to pass a variable to a server tag?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a webforms user control "Widgets:Fancy" that has a property "Time". I need to pass current time to it but neither of those works:

```
<Widgets:Fancy Time="<%=DateTime.Now%>" Runat="Server">
<Widgets:Fancy Time=<%=DateTime.Now%> Runat="Server">
<Widgets:Fancy Time=DateTime.Now Runat="Server">
<Widgets:Fancy Time="DateTime.Now" Runat="Server">
```

I either get the literal value or an error.. obviously these are not the ways to do it. How do I pass something to it?

Comment: If control is inside some data binding context (e.g. GridView) - you can use `<%# %>`. Otherwise give control some ID and use code-behind

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo: all your server tags are not closed

Comment: @RubensFarias Thats a typo over here only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Page Load of your content page, call the `DataBind` method like this:-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not IsPostBack) Then
        Page.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, you can use it with `#` within your code nuggets:-

```
<Widgets:Fancy Time='<%# DateTime.Now %> runat="server">
```